# Correctly add textures to .obj in threejs

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js, textures

I am currently trying to add textures to an `.obj`. I have downloaded (https://www.cgtrader.com/free-3d-models/character/anatomy/eyeball--3). The texture is like this:

[image: Eyeball and Iris Texture]

I have loaded the image to the `obj` in three.js just like an example from three.js suggested:

TEXTURE:

```
    var loader = new THREE.ImageLoader( manager );
    loader.load( 'textures/Eye_D.jpg', function ( image ) {

        texture.image = image;
        texture.needsUpdate = true;

    } );
```

MODEL:

```
    var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader( manager );
    loader.load( 'obj/eyeball.obj', function ( object ) {
                object.scale.set(25, 25, 25)

                object.traverse( function ( child ) {

                    if ( child instanceof THREE.Mesh ) {

                        child.material.map = texture;

                    }

                } );

                object.position.y = 5;
                scene.add( object );

            }, onProgress, onError );
```

However, I don't know how to correctly add the texture(s) as the iris should be textured separately. It currently looks like this:

[image]

Comment: You mesh has 3 textures.
You should have a .mtl file along with the .obj file. This file contains the textures to render on the mesh. Did you try the OBJ + MTL loader?
https://threejs.org/examples/?q=obj#webgl_loader_obj_mtl

Comment: @neeh ahhh ! this should be it! Thanks!!

Comment: ;-) Don't forget to add a light. Also, you may want to remove bump maps by commenting lines starting with `map_Bump` in the .mtl file.

Comment: or you can look [here](http://west77.ru/content/r84/eyeball.html)(source code: Ctrl + U) to see how to remove `bumpMap` parameter from materials of `THREE.MultiMaterial()` without changing the .mtl file